# Connecting SDl 1.25 to Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, sdl

I just freshly installed Xcode 6.1 and SDL 1.25. I am trying to link them and get a simple template going so I can finally get this underway.

I have searched far and wide through the internet to find this but there doesn't seem to be any tutorials with correct information on how to set up an SDL_Template and linking the directory correctly.

Comment: Why would you want to use SDL 1.2 when SDL 2.0 is released which is better in terms of bug fixes, hardware rendering support and ongoing development?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you use SDL 2.0 rather than SDL 1.2 but if you really must use 1.2 Lazy Foo's tutorial will still work even though it was done in Xcode 4.4

http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php

If you want to use SDL 2.0 then this tutorial shows the setup for it and also comes with a handy template pre-made

http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/